# Как узнать находится ли конкретный файл в конкретной директории?

Tags: node.js

Есть ссылка на директорию содержащую вложенные папки и файлы и есть ссылка на определённый файл. Как способ, узнать, находится ли определенный файл в директории, будет самым оптимальным?
Или какие способы вообще есть? Просто я вообще не знаю node.js, но нужно сделать маленькую поделку. А учить... Желание есть но время нет :( По этому, буду рад любым ответам.
Сам могу только открытием для чтения, но возможно есть что-то более подходящие...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то у них половина документации ни о чем.

Можно проверить через [fs.exists(path, callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_fs_exists_path_callback), но им не рекомендуют пользоваться, так как это антипаттерн. Рекомендованный способ, открыть файл [fs.open(path, flags, [mode], callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) и проверить на ошибку.

```
fs.open("readme.txt", "r+", 0644, function(err, file_handle) {
    if (!err) {
        // Операции с открытым файлом
    } else {
        // Обработка ошибок
    }
});
```

Comment: @Alex Krass: Спасибо! С локами у них действительно сложно, особенно на русском.